# Change text in a datagridview fed from a datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to change the text in one of the columns of a datagridview, that is fed from a datatable for the purpose of a presentation (specifically I want to translate the terms there to another language) . I assume I can do this by moving the entire data to my own table and modify it there, but I rather not if it is avoidable. Any idea ?

Comment: Is your Datagrid bound to the datatable?

Comment: yes, the first line is this.dataGridView1.DataSource = mydatatable;

Comment: I've taken the information from original (now deleted) question that you don't want to change the data - only the displayed text, and answered according to that. Let me know if that no longer stands. Also - for translation you might be better off extracting the data and translating it before it is in the datatable and before it reaches the datagridview. The cell formatting approach is more meant for changing things like codes to meaningful text.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this with the DataGridView is to use the CellFormating event, described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) on MSDN. There is a nice example of what you can do in a [HowTo Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h.aspx), but I've also given an overview here.

First you need to subscribe to the `CellFormating` event, either through the design view or through code:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting);
```

Then in the event handler you place your logic to format your data for display:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["InterestingColumn"].Index)
    {
        if (e.Value == null)
            return;

        if (e.Value.ToString() == "TargetValue")
        {
            e.Value = "DisplayValue";
        }
    }
}
```

This does not alter the underlying value in the DataSet - only the displayed value, and the event triggers after each cell leave event, so users can type data into the grid (if it is not readonly) and the formatting will be applied.

Of course all this is customisable as you wish, but the CellFormating event is the best place to start.

Comment: Thanks! it worked, although I had to remove the first condition (datagridview1.Rows[e.ColumIndex].IsNewRow. Why would you use the column index as an index of a row ?

Comment: Sorry - that was just a typo. You would of course use the row index. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is Bind the DataGridView and the DataTable properly.

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

bs.Datasource = mydatatable;

dataGridView1.Datasource = bs;
```

Any changes you make in the DataTable will reflect in the datagrid automatically and vice versa.

Next, you could perhaps iterate through each row in your DataTable. You can translate the value in in your designated column for each row. Something like this :-

```
foreach(DataRow row in mydatatable.rows)
{
    // Do your translation code

    row["SpecificColumnName"] = yourTranslatedvalue;
}
```

Its pretty basic stuff, but it may help you get a  start.